# AngularJS - Passing parameters from directive back to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a new-be to Javascript and AngularJS but I have some Java experience. I'm studying AngularJS [developer's guide on directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and have a question.

In the section "Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements" there is a [example/demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/MD1lRpMyINwEvgtXuUN2?p=preview). In the example/demo:

The template of the directive `myDialog` is as below:

```
<div class="alert">
  <a href class="close" ng-click="close({message: 'closing for now'})">&times;</a>
  <div ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

I cannot understand `close({message: 'closing for now'})` here. From the directive's definition:

```
scope: {
  'close': '&onClose'
}
```

So `close` is a reference to `onClose` in the directive's parent.  `onClose` is not defined in the controller but appears in its template as an attribute and further refer to `hideDialog(message)`:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  {{message}}
  <my-dialog ng-hide="dialogIsHidden" on-close="hideDialog(message)">
    Check out the contents, {{name}}!
  </my-dialog>
</div>
```

Questions:

1. Since `onClose` is not specifically defined in the controller, how can it take and process any input parameter passed from the directive?
2. `hideDialog` in the controller takes a string parameter, but `close` in the directive passes an object `{message: 'closing for now'}` to `onClose`. how `onClose` does the magic of extracting the value from the `message` key of the input and passing it to the target function `hideDialog`?

Comment: This is all explained very clearly in the 4 paragraphs of text directly beneath the example in the documentation you linked.  It's not really clear what part of the documentation you don't understand, but your questions make it apparent that you didn't actually read the explanation.

Comment: @Chaies: I don't think the paragraphs you mentioned exactly explained how the object are processed and passed to the target function. `ng-lick` is mentioned. but no details of how it is invoked and works.

Comment: "When the user clicks the `x` in the dialog, the directive's `close` function is called, thanks to `ng-click`. This call to `close` on the isolated scope actually evaluates the expression `hideDialog(message)` in the context of the original scope, thus running Controller's `hideDialog` function." Is that the portion of the documentation you are looking for clarification on?

Comment: @Chaies: Actually it does not answer any of the two questions I asked (how the parameter is passed and processed). But thanks to your comment, it provides some clue. But I checked the ngClick API spec and did not get it so far.

Comment: again, going back to that same documentation section:  "Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolate scope via an expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper function.".  So in this example, the `map` is the `object`, `message: 'closing for now'` is the local variable name and value.